# Can't access to classes static element

Tags: java, class, oop, methods

I have an object called `SharedBoard` and it is a static entity so I want it to be shared by all the classes. I have this method `getBoard()`, which returns the `SharedBoard` object; however, I always get a `NullPointerException` when I try to call this method from another class. I actually can't even print the elements in the board from this method. Am I missing an OOP concept somewhere?

```
public class Server {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static SharedBoard board;

    // The set of all the print writers for all the clients, used for broadcast.
    private Set<PrintWriter> writers = new HashSet<>();

    public Server(ServerSocket serverSocket) {
        this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
        Server.board = new SharedBoard();
    }

    public static SharedBoard getBoard() {
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
            System.out.println(board.moves[i]);
        return board;
    }
```

And here is the part of `SharedBoard` class/constructor:

```
public class SharedBoard {

    private final Object lock = new Object();
    int[] moves;

    SharedBoard() {

        moves = new int[9];

        for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
                moves[i] = 0;
    }

.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Does your code create a `Server` object anywhere?  If it doesn't, then that line `Server.board = new SharedBoard();` won't have run, so `board` will still be null.

Comment: Actually, you are right. I just have a reference to a server. That is why it wasnt working thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor of `Server` class is not invoked. So thus the statement `Server.board = new SharedBoard();` is not invoked and it will always be null. So you get NPE from `System.out.println(board.moves[i]);` from this statement.

we can solve this by 
Initialize the server object from constructor or use static initializer block to initialize board object

```
class Server {
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static SharedBoard board;

static {
    board = new SharedBoard();
}

// The set of all the print writers for all the clients, used for broadcast.
private Set<PrintWriter> writers = new HashSet<>();

public Server(ServerSocket serverSocket) {
    this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
}

public static SharedBoard getBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        System.out.println(board.moves[i]);
    return board;
    }
}
```

Or initialize directly in class

```
private static SharedBoard board= new SharedBoard();
```

Answer (score 0):

When class is loaded all the static members are initialized and loaded into memory with the default value. So **SharedBoard** is the static variable of Server class that's why your **SharedBoard** is initialized with default value i.e null.

So while loading your static variable you have to instantiate your **SharedBoard** manually in SIB (static block) like...

```
static {
     board = new SharedBoard();
}
```